# Limit of the root of quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

The root of the equation
$
a x^2 + bx + c = 0
$
is given by 
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \;\;\;...(1)
$$

On the other hand, if $a = 0$, then from the original equation we get
$$
x = - \frac{c}{b}  \;\;\;...(2)
$$

So I am guessing that as $a \to 0$, one of the root in (1) converges to
(2), and the other diverges, but I cannot formally prove it.

Can someone give me a proof, or is my guess incorrect?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60799/242) for a view more conceptual than rationalizing the numberator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The case $c=0$ requires separate treatment. For $c\ne 0$. multiply top and bottom by $-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$, do some cancellation, and take the limit as $a\to 0$. Your guess will be confirmed.

*Remark*: When you do the multiplication and cancellation, you will obtain the *Citardauq Formula* for the roots of the quadratic.

Comment: ...Did you really just write the word "quadratic" backwards?

Comment: Yes. In my defense, I did not invent the name!  The formula can in fact be computationally useful, in cases of catastrophic almost cancellation.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Very clear!

Comment: @KotaMori: You are welcome.