# Help solving a limit in two parts $\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm trying to solve a limit problem but I've never encountered the one like this before.

$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)$$

I multiply the right side by $\frac{t\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}}$ and combine the terms to get:

$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1 - t\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}}\right)$$

I can factor out the $t\sqrt{1+t}$ and I am left with:

$$1 - 1 = 0$$

This seems wrong to me. I can't explain why, maybe I just feel that getting a zero after all that work seems lame. Am I following the right steps?

Comment: Why would you multiply by $\frac{t \sqrt{1+t}}{t \sqrt{1+t}}$ when the right-hand term already has a $t$ in the denominator.  Additionally, when you do, you don't get the denominator you claim to get.

Comment: @Irresponsible, limit is $t\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: This is in the form $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60341

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}-1\right)\right]=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{\sqrt{1+t}}\right)\right]=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{\sqrt{1+t}}\right)\frac{1+\sqrt{1+t}}{1+\sqrt{1+t}}\right]=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1-{1-t}}{\sqrt{1+t}}\right)\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+t}}\right]=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+t}(1+\sqrt{1+t})}=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Comment: first limit you wrote, will be $t\rightarrow 0$

Comment: yeah!! Thanks @lavkush

Answer (score 3):

Using L'Hopital's rule,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}-1}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}-1\right)}{\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\right)}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-1}{2(t+1)^{3/2}}\\
&=-\frac12.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply L' Hospital rule . . The answer is $- \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: This answer was shown earlier, with more explanation, by David H.

Answer (score 0):

If you learnt Taylor series, the problem can be adddressed in a very simple form since, built around $t=0$, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}=1-\frac{t}{2}+O\left(t^2\right)$$ from which the remaining becomes very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a solution that computes the right limit $t\to 0^+$ [image: This is the my solution. Here I use a trigonometric substitution.]

Answer (score 0):

Once you corrected your second formula to
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\left(\frac1{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\frac1t\right)
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{t}\ \lim_{t\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{1+t}}
\end{align}
$$
You can use L'Hospital on the left limit and just plug $t=0$ into the right limit.