# Finding $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{9x^2+x} - 3x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I am trying to find the limit and I know that I have to do something to get a denominator but I can't make it work. There is a specific thing I have to do to this problem to make it work but I am not sure what that is. I know what I am doing is not wrong mathematically, it just doesn't help me get the answer.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{9x^2+x} - 3x)$$

Not sure where to go with this, multiply it all by the conjugate? I tried that but I know that won't help because I have to rationalize the denominator. I know I can't multiply by anything really until I get rid of the sqrt and I don't know how.

Comment: You have to rationalize the denominator? Says who?

Comment: Yes, multiply and divide by the conjugate. You won't have to rationalize the denominator. Try it.

Comment: I thought it was a rule.

Comment: I multiplied by the conjugate and I think I got x on the top since the rest cancelled out and then conjugate on the bottom. I think that reduces to 3 if I divide everything by x, which gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: I've always wondered why high school teachers make such a big deal about rationalizing denominators for no reason... it never made sense to me

Comment: Nothing in math makes sense to me. Whenever you ask why you are either told not to worry or referred to a massive proof that requires 8 years of college to understand.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3x}.$$
Divide numerator and denominator by $x$,
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3}$$
note $\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{9x^2+x}=\sqrt{\frac{9x^2+x}{x^2}}=\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x}}$ so this reduces to
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x}}+3}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{9}+3}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
And just FYI this ground was (*more or less*) covered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040/limits-how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnxna-n-1x).

Comment: I don't understand how 9x^2 turns into (9+1/x)

Comment: @Jordan You divide the numerator and denominator by $x$. The first term alone looks like $\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{9x^2+x}$. Can you then bring the $1/x$ inside the square root? What will happen to it then?

Comment: @Jordan: I edited it with an explanation.

Comment: I don't understand where the 1/x infront came from, would that make the whole numerator 0?

Comment: @Jordan: If you divide $\sqrt{9x^2+x}$ by $x$ you get $\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{9x^2+x}$. What makes you think this makes the numerator $0$?

Comment: 1/infinity is zero/

Comment: @Jordan: But 1/infinity times the square root of 9infinity^2+infinity is a whole different story...

Comment: I get it now, I just wish I could do these on my own. I burn through all the homework problems with assistance, spending an entire day and then forget it all.

Comment: "How did $9x^2$ turn into $9 + 1/x$?" is a question that I heard a pretty large number of times last time I assigned this problem.  It is precisely in that step that it matters that it's $+\infty$ rather than $-\infty$.  If $x>0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}$ is the same as $x$, but if $x<0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ and the answer is quite different.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use your previous question: [Finding $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{9+h} -3)}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60220/finding-lim-limits-h-to-0-frac-sqrt9h-3h) , where you got the limit was $1/6$.

Indeed, to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} (\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x)$, if you let $x=1/h$, then as $x\to +\infty$ you get $h\to 0^+$. So:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} (\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x)= \lim_{h\to 0^+} \left(\sqrt{\frac{9}{h^2}+\frac{1}{h}}-\frac{3}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{h^2}(9+h)}-\frac{3}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{9+h}-3}{h}= \frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

Factoring out the $9x^2$ from inside the radical, then applying the binomial theorem (or Taylor series or whatever) to get the partial series: $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{9x^2+x}-3x)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}3x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9x}}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}3x\left(\frac{1}{18x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is that O?

Comment: @Jordan: that is the "[big-$O$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)".  Here, $O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ represents a quantity for which there is a $C>0$ so that the absolute value of that quantity is smaller than $C\times\frac{1}{x^2}$ as $x\to\infty$.